# Trouble passing data to a child component with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

The structure of the project is where my **App.js** gets the user location when it loads. I want to take this information and pass it down to a child component. The reason I set it up like this is that I will have 3 components that all need to use the location data.

I am really close to getting this to work, but I cannot seem to get the data over to the Weather component. The App compiles successfully but it will not render the data I want it to. I feel like I am so, so close but need that push to get over the cliff.

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import './App.css'; 
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Weather from './components/Weather'

// Defining our <App /> component the function name matches the file name
function App() {

    const [location, setLocation] = useState({lat: 0, long: 0})

    useEffect(()=>{
      const success = (position) =>{ 
        let lat = position.coords.latitude
        let long = position.coords.longitude
   
        
        console.log(lat, long)
        setLocation({lat: lat, long: long})
        // I have also tried ({lat, long})
        
      }
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success)
      
    },[])



  const routes = ['nasa','openweather','zomato']

  return ( 
    <div className="App"> 

    {/* Establish Navigation for the website */}
      <Navbar routes={routes} />
      <Route exact path="/nasa"></Route>


     <Route exact path="/openweather">
        <Weather position={location} />
      </Route>
```

Here is the Weather component

```
const Weather = ({ position }) => {
    return(
        <div>
        <p> long: {position.long}</p>
        <p> lat: {position.lat}</p>
      
        </div>
    )
}

export default Weather
```

Comment: I think there should be an argument in your `setLocation()`? It's empty, so presumably the value would be set to `undefined`.

Comment: As long as your logic belongs to `Weather` component, why not moving this inside it?

Comment: @AdriSolid - Because this Geolocation data needs to be used by three different components, and they need to fetch an API. The user lands on the App.js page, so I thought it would be best to have the location there to be used by the children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great! You've the basic idea but you are missing a little attention to your app state and everything will be okay.

1- note that you didn't pass any value to set the `location` state

```js
    // first it has started with undefined
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(); // you should have passed an initila state here...
```

should be

```js
    // put any default long & lat you find suitable
    const [location, setLocation] = useState({ lat: 33.232, long: 35.125 });
```

and when you set the new state you didn't pass anything to the set function

```js
      setLocation()
```

where it should be

```js
      setLocation({ long: <xxx>, lat: <xxx> });
```

2- and as I can see from your code that line should be inside the `success` callback where you get the actual long and lat.

3- and finally when you've passed down the state to the child component you didn't specify any property from your state(maybe because you didn't have a structure for your state yet)

```js
        <p> {position}</p>
```

should be

```js
   <p> long: {position.long}</p>
   <p> lat:  {position.lat}</p>
```

Comment: I made the changes, but the position still doesn't render in the child's JSX. When you say long: <xxx>, I put setLocation({lat: lat, long: long}), as my variable should store that value. I also tried just leaving only the variable names.

Comment: can you update your question's code to reflect the changes so we can easily detect the problem

Comment: Are you sure this line `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success)
` get executed at least once?

Comment: Yes, I can get the coordinates in the console.log(lat, long).

Comment: Sorry but Where should `Weather` have been used? I can't see it in code

Comment: My fault, I didn't copy it in the question when I edited it. It is in App.js in the return ()

Comment: I'm sorry but I feel like missing something because the code isn't complete, is your `<Route>` nested inside a `<Router>` from `react-router-dom`?

Comment: Your answer was correct! It worked perfectly. I was making a routing mistake in the browser.

Comment: @LouayAlosh zero is not a good sentinel value because it's a valid latitude and longitude value. OP should probably pass an empty object and check `if ("lat" in location)` to see if it's been populated.

Comment: You're right, or can put some default lat and long, thank you for these details